# My smoke is blocky even at highish resolutions

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation, fire, mantaflow

I’m working on this project where I’m getting this blockiness in the fiery smoky flying rocks.
I already increased the resolution of the bake to 500 in the domain menu and it took the whole day to bake even in my mildly beefy machine (3900x, RTX3090, 64GB RAM). Is there anything else I can do to make the blockiness go away and make it look more realistic?
I’m fairly new to simulations so I don’t want to be messing with stuff I don’t completely understand and waiting around for whole days to get bakes done...

Clarifications:

- I'm working on Cycles (needed for the pointiness value in the geometry nodes for the planet exploding material)
- I don't think it is a volume thing as the simulation already looks pretty jagged out of the bake.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: it's worth checking the related questions, but i had the same problem using eevee and lowering the Tile Size under Volumetrics in the Render Properties helped a lot (without having to bake again)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Added a clarification to the original post as to why I don't think the issue lies there. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was a combination of setting an 'initial velocity' on the emitter from its normal of about $0.02$ and then using the *Vorticity* control on the *Volume* from about $0.4$ to $0.7$ and then a resolution of about $300$ upwards should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting to interpolate volumes in the material settings in volume tab.
Change the interpolation from linear to Cubic.

[image]

The resolution of simulation is one thing, but how the cubic voxels are interpolated is another. In the simplest case, the voxels are like minecraft cubes and even at very high resolution, they will look bad. However if you use cubic interpolation, they get smoothed.

Comment: Thank you, I think this should be marked as the correct answer!